# reading smtp port from IIS settings

Tags: asp.net, iis, smtp, port

In my web.config file I have specified settings for sending mail. In particular I have these settings:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp>
            <network host="smtp.example.com" port="25" userName="user" password="pass"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Now the problem is that my isp suddently (without warning of course) have decided to block port 25 meaning I have to change to port 26 in my development envoiremnet. I belive the best way would be to change to port 26 in the IIS manager (this way I do not need to change anything when publishing my webapp to the remote server).

But how do I tell my asp.net webapp to use the default IIS setting?

Answer (score 0):

check port no 587 its also use for smtp because most of ISP and web hoster block port 25 for security reason.

Comment: Thanks for info, but this does not solve my problem. Please read question again.

Comment: do one thing create SMTP table in database, so and use that information to send mail , so you can change that without publish site, i am always give some setting to client, so they can change